# Scripted Dashboards for Graphite

Tags: json, dashboard, graphite, kibana

I am trying to generate dashboards for some metrics using graphite. Ideally, if i would like to display metrics such as CPU usage, Memory, and log statistics stored in graphite whisper DB. Is there any tool (and documentation) such as kibana3 which supports scripted dash-boards. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Grafana (http://grafana.org) it is based on Kibana.

Answer (score 2):

Generated graphs can be configured and saved in the following ways-

```
1. Dashboard
```

The dashboard can be accessed at- `http://graphite-url/dashboard`. Once you display the graph(s), you can configure the size, lineMode, etc. Once done, save the dashboard by going to `dashboard -> save as`.

```
2. Composer
```

While installing graphite webapp, the django user auth details can be used to log into the webapp. Once logged in, every graph will have a `save` icon on the top-left of the composer window. Saved graphs will be saved under `user-graphs`, under the metric-tree.

```
3. Render endpoint
```

If by 'scripting' you meant content, than rendering, use the [render URL](https://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/render_api.html) endpoint. Generate the required url by script and do something like- `http://graphite-host/composer/&target=a.b.c&target=d.*.e.f`

Comment: I tried to query for graphs using render uri api from graphite, now i would like to query for data in json and not in graphical image. Once i acquire the data in json, i shall use the highcharts to plot.. (check this link) http://jsfiddle.net/68BQy/3/.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean but for example using the graph-explorer graphite dashboard you can go to "/dashboard/server-basics/insert_hostname_here" and it will server graphs (cpu, memory, diskspace) for the given hostname. you can change the dashboards or add more to do the same things for other metrics.

edit: this does assume that the plugins that it uses were able to parse your metrics.